# There is a database of `import PACKAGE` with `pip install PACKAGE_NAME`

Tags: python, pip, python-import

There are many package that is different the `import package_namex` vs `pip install package-namey`
A example of this is the package [egenix-mx-base](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/egenix-mx-base/)
You import with:
`import mx`
But you install with
`pip install egenix-mx-base`

Are there a way of get the pip install command from the import sentence?

e.g. If you use `import mx` then you will need to execute `pip install egenix-mx-base`

Comment: There is also `pip search`....

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from os.path import dirname
import my_module

print(dirname(my_module.__file__))  # NOTE: Python 3.x
```

This will tell you the physical location of the module on your filesystem, and you can deduce the library name from it.

Maybe not exactly what you were asking for, but it might still be good enough for your problem.